# Center column of GridView Overriding GridView CssClass

Tags: css, gridview, text, alignment, center

I have a GridView using a few css classes, that is okay.

The problem is that applying individual Css classes to the boundfield of the gridview is not being applied..

Here is My grid view:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvwExample" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed epalist gridtextcenter" EmptyDataText="The search didn't return any records" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowDataBound="gvwExample_RowDataBound" >
                    <columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="NB"  ItemStyle-CssClass="textleft" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-Width="6%" HeaderText="NB" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ItemStyle-Width="19%" HeaderText="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CLevel" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="6%" HeaderText="CLevel" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CC Host" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="CC Host" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="System"  ItemStyle-Width="15%" HeaderText="System" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Object Type"  ItemStyle-Width="12%" HeaderText="Object Type" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Object ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="8%" HeaderText="Object ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Object Description" ItemStyle-Width="17%" HeaderText="Object Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Excl Mngr" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="9%"  HeaderText="Excl Mngr" />
                    </columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my CssClass of the first column "NB":

```
.textleft{
    text-align:left;
}
.gridtextcenter td, .gridtextcenter th{
    text-align:center;
}
```

So the main thing is:
the class "gridtextcenter" will center all the text of all my td, but the first column use the css class "textleft" that should place the text not centered, why is not working??

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: because `.gridtextcenter td` has more specificity than `.textleft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.gridtextcenter td` has more specificity than `.textleft`

write your css in this way

```
.gridtextcenter .textleft{
    text-align:left;
}
.gridtextcenter td, .gridtextcenter th{
    text-align:center;
}
```

How **Specificity** works :

1 = for all type of tags like `<p>, <a>`

10 = for class like `.className`

100 = for id like `#idName`